# How to make area be irregular shape not rectangle?

Tags: svg

How to make area be irregular shape not rectangle?
I used svg code like below, tried to make a map but I just can't get it how to make mouse over or click the area not rectangle be just like the vector what i draw.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra4BF/

```
<svg version="1.1" class="flag_link_0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="190.323px" height="325.806px" viewBox="0 0 190.323 325.806" enable-background="new 0 0 190.323 325.806" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon fill="#A71F20" points="10.839,314.677 181.839,314.677 181.839,48.186 10.839,9.677 "/>
</svg>

 $('.flag_link_0').hover(function(){
    console.log('in');
},function(){

});
```

Comment: What is the problem, the event is triggered, fiddle seems to be working ok. Are you trying to draw a curved shape?

Comment: I am trying to find the way only hover the red area then trigger event  ? if I use <map><area shape> tag it is so hard to location area only use code, so I use illustrator drawing then export svg code like jsfiddle..

Comment: Are you trying to run a function for an event other than hover, like clicking on the shape?

Comment: ?? I am trying to make a shape not only rectangle can be hover, just like http://christianheilmann.com/2013/06/10/irregular-shape-rollovers-with-canvas-and-png/  but use svg not canvas

Comment: Select the polygon, not the SVG: `$('.flag_link_0 polygon').hover(...`. The SVG **is** a rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pure CSS to achieve the results you are looking for.  Add an `id/class` to your `svg`, in this case I added an `id` of `poly1`.

Here is your svg modified JSFiddle:  [>>>CLICK HERE<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/Ra4BF/1/)

SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" class="flag_link_0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  mlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="190.323px" height="325.806px" viewBox="0 0 190.323 325.806" enable-background="new 0 0 190.323 325.806" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon fill="#A71F20" stroke="#A71F20" stroke-width="3px" id="poly1" points="10.839,314.677 181.839,314.677 181.839,48.186 10.839,9.677 " />
```

CSS:

```
#poly1:hover {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #A71F20;
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
```