# CSS Design Advice - abnormal CSS polygons with border-radius and box shadow

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to practice my CSS skills on advanced areas of CSS and I must say, I've become absolutely stumped in recreating a DIV with the following design:

[image]

So essentially I want the div to have an "abnormal polygon shape/border" but I have no clue how I would go about doing that (plus a box shadow too). I believe you could use clip-path maybe? But I'm not 100% sure..

EDIT: to be clearer, I’m trying to find a solution which allows for: responsiveness, border-radius around the abnormal shape a box-shadow too, which is more complex than some of the other questions,

Comment: Somewhat, but not entirely. I already knew about the trick of clip-path, but it doesn't solve my solution of using box-shadow.  Clip-path cuts off anything outside of the path, including the shadows.

Comment: read all the answers, there not only a clip-path idea

Comment: Hmm I see. One uses perspectives to create the effect. I might give that a shot. I think this might be a bit tricky to make the div responsive.

Comment: Actually also on that topic, this technique might not work too well with border radiuses, as per the image I posted. So essentially, I'm trying to think of a way which provides box shadows, border radius, the abnormal shape and responsiveness.

Comment: you said *but rather just looking for tips* --> I gave you more that a tips so you can probably to a small effort to give a try with what I gave you? as a side note you question is off topic

Comment: Yes I understand and thank you for the help, but it’s part of the question I’m trying to find an answer to :) I have edited the question now to make it a bit more clearer

Answer (score 1):

One of the kaywords You're looking for -> SVG, Clip-path

Take a look here -> [How to make area be irregular shape not rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619309/how-to-make-area-be-irregular-shape-not-rectangle)
or here -> https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

Comment: That CSS tricks article is quite helpful. Thanks for that